# Logarithmic derivative of Riemann Zeta function

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Given the logarithmic derivative of the zeta function $\dfrac{\zeta^\prime (s)}{\zeta(s)}$ how does it behave near $s=1$?

I mean if for $s=1$ the Laurent series for the logarithmic derivative becomes

$$\frac{\zeta^\prime (s)}{\zeta(s)}= A+ (s-1)^{-1}$$

where $A$ is a real number constant.

Comment: The $A$ you have there is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $\gamma$. Actually, your series goes like $\frac{\zeta^\prime (s)}{\zeta(s)}=-\frac1{s-1}+\gamma-(\gamma^2+2\gamma_1)(s-1)+\cdots$ where $\gamma_1$ is the first Stieltjes constant.

Comment: Not directly related but the following is associated with a symmetric matrix: $$-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)\right)$$
https://oeis.org/A191898

Comment: @Mats where can I find a proof of that statement?

Comment: @kaffeeauf Starting from the mentioned matrix to arrive at this generating function I don't know how to prove the generating function for it. However the truth of the statement:
$$-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)\right)$$ I have been told by I think it was user Lucia at mathoverflow, that this is standard definition of the derivative somehow. Also, Mathematica knows that this statement is true: Limit[Zeta[s]*Zeta[c]/Zeta[s + c - 1] - Zeta[c], c -> 1]   


The answer at mathoverflow got down voted so I deleted it.

Answer (score 18):

Let's generalize and look at all of the constants in the Laurent expansion.  Consider $$-\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(s+1)=\frac{1}{s}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\eta_j s^j.$$  (I put in a negative sign so it corresponds to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n)n^{-s}$.) I claim that $\eta_0 =-\gamma_0$, Euler's Constant, and that in general $\eta_j$ will be a sum of products of the [Stieltjes constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

**Constants arising from a limit:**  It is interesting to note that in a way analogous to the fact that the Stieltjes constants are given by the limit $$\gamma_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\left(\sum_{k = 1}^m  \frac{(\log k)^n}{k}\right) - \frac{(\log m)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)},$$ we have that $$\eta_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\left(\sum_{k = 1}^m  \frac{(\log k)^{n}\Lambda(k)}{k}\right) - \frac{(\log m)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)}$$ where $\Lambda(n)$ is the [von Mangoldt Lambda Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function). This can be proven by using exponential generating series, and then the Dirichlet series for $-\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(s).$

**Computing the Constants:** We can compute $\eta_j$ in terms of the [Stieltjes constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) by using the relation $$\log\left(1+\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\gamma_j s^{j+1}\right)= \log (s\zeta(s+1))=-\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\eta_j s^j$$

and then expanding by using the identity $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$$

From this we get the power series $$\gamma_0 s-\left(2\gamma_1+\gamma_0^2\right)\frac{s^2}{2}+\left(3\gamma_2+6\gamma_1\gamma_0+2\gamma_0^3\right)\frac{s^3}{6}+\cdots$$ so that $$\eta_0 =-\gamma, \ \ \ \eta_1 =-(2\gamma_1 +\gamma_0^2), \ \ \ \eta_2 =-(3\gamma_2 +6\gamma_1\gamma_0 +2\gamma_0^3) \qquad \text{et cetera}.$$

Answer (score 6):

As an addendum to Eric's answer, [Coffey](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2003.09.003) gives a recursion relation for the coefficients $\dfrac{\eta_j}{j!}$ appearing in the expansion of the $\zeta$ function's logarithmic derivative. Letting $\gamma_k$ be the Stieltjes constants, and with the initial condition $\eta_0=-\gamma_0=-\gamma$, we have the recursion relation

$$\frac{\eta_j}{j!}=(-1)^{j+1}\left(\frac{j+1}{j!}\gamma_j+\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(j-k-1)!}\frac{\eta_k}{k!}\gamma_{j-k-1}\right)$$

A similar formula also appears in [Choudhury's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1995.0096).