# Laurent expansion of $ \log\zeta(s) $

Tags: riemann-zeta

Is it possible to expand the logarithm of the zeta function

$$ \log\zeta (s)= a_{0}+a_{1}s^{-1}+a_{2}s^{-2}+.... ,$$

with coefficients $ a_{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint dz \frac{\log\zeta(z)}{z^{n+1}} $ ?

My idea is to improve the Gram series based on the solution of the integral equation

$$ \log\zeta (s)=s\int_{0}^{\infty}dt \frac{\pi(e^{t})}{e^{st}-1}. $$

Of course I am almost sure that the coefficients $ a_{n} $ must depend on the nontrivial zeros of Riemann zeta $ \zeta (\rho)=0 $.

Comment: Do you really mean $a_1^{-s}$ ... or $a_1 s^{-1}$, which would be a Laurent series.

Comment: Your expansion should be valid where?  And your integral $\oint$ is around what contour?

Comment: mistake corrected, the idea is to expand the logarithm of riemann zeta $ log\zeta (s) $ as a Z-transform , see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_transform

Comment: This question and its answers might be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71095/logarithmic-derivative-of-riemann-zeta-function.

Comment: My guess: $\log \zeta(s)$ is not regular at infinity, and thus does not have an expansion of this form.

Comment: perhaps if we could prove that (approximately) $ log\zeta (s) \sim -log(1-1/s) $ then we would have the expansion $log\zeta (s) \approx \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ns^{n}}$